# How can I use a string input to determine file name?

Tags: python, string, filenames

I am receiving a string as an input, and that will determine the file associated with the function needed.
i.e. If I receive `"File1"` I want to use `File1.function()`, if I receive `"File2"` I want to use `File2.function`.

Comment: Like, do you have a list of all the files alrady?

Comment: or are you checking your entire computer, or will you create an entirely new file depending on the file input

Comment: I already have a list of files

Comment: oh if you have a list of files then it should be simple, you can just index the point of the list where that is and open the file and assign it to a variable.

Comment: Generally speak you _don't_ need (or want) to create variables with names not known until runtime. See the related question [How do I create a variable number of variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-a-variable-number-of-variables)

Answer (score 0):

You may use the `execfile()` or `os.system()` but this is dangerous if the filename comes from an untrusted source. Do never do this in public internet!